# Unable to install the catkin_tools packages for ROS on Ubuntu 20.04 with apt-get

Tags: ros, ubuntu-20.04, catkin

I have been trying to download catkin tools, but it keeps giving me errors that the command is not found. Please refer to the pictures down below. I have ROS noetic downloaded on here and the gazebo enviornment application is on her, but even then it is not allowing me to install the toolbox.

> [[terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfeVR.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZw0J.png)

I tried copying and pasting the commands from the catkin tools installation website, but it didn't work. I expected it to download, but it resulted into telling me that the command was not found

Comment: Have you tried pasting the commands one by one?